# Avoid body scroll width on DIV table header

Tags: css, html

I have a DIV table, with a DIV as a header and other DIV called "`tableContent`", containing several DIVS as content. Each first DIv of each row (incl. header) is 60%, second one 20%, and the other two are 10%. --- [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4D9tb/1/)

The problem comes whith the property `overflow-y:scroll` on `tableContent`, that is needed as `tableContent` has a fixed height and all overflowing content must be seen by scrolling. You can see here how table imbalances due to this: header and conten columns are not at the same width:

[image: imbalance]

This is due to the fact that now 100% of `tableContent` includes the 16px of the scroll

How can I make header divs and content divs ave the same final width?

HTML code:

```
<div class="tableWrap">
<div class="tableHeader">
            <div class="contentColumn60 tableHeaderColumn">
                <span class="tableHeaderText">Turno</span>
            </div>
            <div class="contentColumn20 tableHeaderColumn">
                <span class="tableHeaderText">Tipo</span>
            </div>
            <div class="contentColumn10 tableHeaderColumn">
                <span class="tableHeaderText">Editar</span>
            </div>
            <div class="contentColumn10 tableHeaderColumn">
                <span class="tableHeaderText">Estado</span>
            </div>

</div>

<div data-id="226" class="tableRow ">
    <div class="contentColumn60">
    <span class="tableContentText">Fín de semana 1 (09:00 - 13:00)</span>
</div>
<div class="contentColumn20">
    <span class="tableContentText">Mañana</span>
</div>
<div class="contentColumn10">
    <div class="tableIconLink"><a href="#"><div title="Fín de semana 1 (09:00 - 13:00)" data-id="226" class="editIcon" style="opacity: 0.5;"></div></a></div>
</div>
<div class="contentColumn10">
    <div class="tableIconLink"><a href="/Gestion/config/forms/turn_conf/turn_discontinue.php?id=226"><div class="discontinueIcon"></div></a></div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div data-id="226" class="tableRow ">
    <div class="contentColumn60">
    <span class="tableContentText">Fín de semana 1 (09:00 - 13:00)</span>
</div>
<div class="contentColumn20">
    <span class="tableContentText">Mañana</span>
</div>
<div class="contentColumn10">
    <div class="tableIconLink"><a href="#"><div title="Fín de semana 1 (09:00 - 13:00)" data-id="226" class="editIcon" style="opacity: 0.5;"></div></a></div>
</div>
<div class="contentColumn10">
    <div class="tableIconLink"><a href="/Gestion/config/forms/turn_conf/turn_discontinue.php?id=226"><div class="discontinueIcon"></div></a></div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div data-id="226" class="tableRow ">
    <div class="contentColumn60">
    <span class="tableContentText">Fín de semana 1 (09:00 - 13:00)</span>
</div>
<div class="contentColumn20">
    <span class="tableContentText">Mañana</span>
</div>
<div class="contentColumn10">
    <div class="tableIconLink"><a href="#"><div title="Fín de semana 1 (09:00 - 13:00)" data-id="226" class="editIcon" style="opacity: 0.5;"></div></a></div>
</div>
<div class="contentColumn10">
    <div class="tableIconLink"><a href="/Gestion/config/forms/turn_conf/turn_discontinue.php?id=226"><div class="discontinueIcon"></div></a></div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div data-id="226" class="tableRow ">
    <div class="contentColumn60">
    <span class="tableContentText">Fín de semana 1 (09:00 - 13:00)</span>
</div>
<div class="contentColumn20">
    <span class="tableContentText">Mañana</span>
</div>
<div class="contentColumn10">
    <div class="tableIconLink"><a href="#"><div title="Fín de semana 1 (09:00 - 13:00)" data-id="226" class="editIcon" style="opacity: 0.5;"></div></a></div>
</div>
<div class="contentColumn10">
    <div class="tableIconLink"><a href="/Gestion/config/forms/turn_conf/turn_discontinue.php?id=226"><div class="discontinueIcon"></div></a></div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div data-id="226" class="tableRow ">
    <div class="contentColumn60">
    <span class="tableContentText">Fín de semana 1 (09:00 - 13:00)</span>
</div>
<div class="contentColumn20">
    <span class="tableContentText">Mañana</span>
</div>
<div class="contentColumn10">
    <div class="tableIconLink"><a href="#"><div title="Fín de semana 1 (09:00 - 13:00)" data-id="226" class="editIcon" style="opacity: 0.5;"></div></a></div>
</div>
<div class="contentColumn10">
    <div class="tableIconLink"><a href="/Gestion/config/forms/turn_conf/turn_discontinue.php?id=226"><div class="discontinueIcon"></div></a></div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div data-id="226" class="tableRow ">
    <div class="contentColumn60">
    <span class="tableContentText">Fín de semana 1 (09:00 - 13:00)</span>
</div>
<div class="contentColumn20">
    <span class="tableContentText">Mañana</span>
</div>
<div class="contentColumn10">
    <div class="tableIconLink"><a href="#"><div title="Fín de semana 1 (09:00 - 13:00)" data-id="226" class="editIcon" style="opacity: 0.5;"></div></a></div>
</div>
<div class="contentColumn10">
    <div class="tableIconLink"><a href="/Gestion/config/forms/turn_conf/turn_discontinue.php?id=226"><div class="discontinueIcon"></div></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.tableWrap{
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    border:#ccc 1px solid;
    border-radius:3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    background: #fbfbfb;
    color:#666;
    font-size: 11px;}


.tableHeader{
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 40px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #EDEDED, #EBEBEB) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E0E0;


}
.tableContent{
    width:100%;
    height: 150px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.tableHeaderText{
     line-height: 40px;
     padding: 0 10px;
     text-align: center;

}

.tableRow{
    height: 36px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fbfbfb;
}

.tableContentText{
    line-height: 36px;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}

.contentColumn60{
    height: 36px;
    width: 60%;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    float: left;
}

.contentColumn20{
    height: 36px;
    width: 20%;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-left:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    float: left;
}

.contentColumn10{
    height: 36px;
    width: 9.5%;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-left:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.tableHeaderColumn{
    border-top:1px solid #fafafa;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.tableIconLink{
    text-align: center;
}

.tableContent .tableRow:hover{
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}




.discontinueIcon{
    width: 21px;
    height: 21px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(images/error.png);
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin: 8px auto;
    display: block;
}

.editIcon{
    width: 21px;
    height: 21px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(images/edit.png);
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin: 8px auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: JSFIDDLE LINK CHANGED. now it shows the problem correctly

Comment: Please see JSFIDDLE link, read explanation and if it is not clear ask me any concrete question in order to explain properly. Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by "header divs fix on width". Do you want header div same to table width?

Comment: I need each DIV on head to have the same width that each DIV on content. Content has smaller DIVS as its 100% includes the 16 px from scrollbar, as this does not happen on head, body's divs and head's divs have a final different width even when thet have both 60%, 20%, 10% and 10% width.

Comment: Question edited to avoid misunderstanding, thanks fos asking @BikashChandraMondal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use CSS3 `calc` to account for the size of the scrollbar

```
.tableHeader {
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 17px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 17px);
    width: -o-calc(100% - 17px);
    width: calc(100% - 17px);
}
```

There are also other ways which you can do this by adding a padding to the right side of the header wrapper.

for that, you would need to add this:

```
.tableHeader {
    padding-right:17px;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;  /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;     /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Comment: Solved. Thank you. In this case, this project is a ERP running only for Moz, so this way is finde for me. Very grateful.

Comment: You're welcome Biomehanika. And thank you @davidkonrad that site was new to me!

Comment: +1 Just saying, but if it is ERP for a known group of users, then calc is a good solution.

Comment: For completeness, I've added a second approach to my answer which does not use `calc` but instead uses `padding` and `box-sizing` which is much more widely supported. http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing